# How to add a new record into an interactive grid using IG methods then set column's value using $s() api?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am using `Oracle Apex 18.2.`

I have an interactive grid and a custom button to add a new row to the IG using,

`apex.region("myRegionStaticId").widget().interactiveGrid('getActions').invoke('row-add-row');` then set a column's value using, `$s("myColumnStaticId","2");`. When I try it, it adds the first row without setting any columns' values and starts setting the value from the second row on. Even using `selection-add-row` or `insert-record`, there is always something with the first row. Here is a sample,

```
[https://apex.oracle.com][1]
ws = ESLAM_WS
user = forhelp
pwd = forhelppwd
app = TEST
page = Add Row on top of an IG.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
$s("INGREDIENT_ID","2");
```

with the following one:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $s("INGREDIENT_ID","2"); }, 100);
```

It seems that the IG needs a little time to render the new row before you are able to change any value.

Comment: That's why it worked well when I tried setting the column's value in a separate "Row Initialization" DA. Good to know the reason but depending on a specific time maybe not a good idea because I do not know the exact time the IG needs to render the new row. It may work times and times not. I think there could be a better solution i.e a callback function or something.

Comment: I actually recommend the answer by Dan McGhan.
It is a few lines more but more accurate. If you measure the performance it is faster as well.

Comment: I used to use Dan's solution long before I posted the question. But I believe adding a row to the grid the way I mentioned could be a better solution. Simply, because you do not need to get the model, the record, etc. It maybe faster because we're waiting for 100 ms. But if we knew the reason the first created row is being late, it then maybe a better solution. Actually, It'd be very helpful if I learn the problem with the first row being late to be rendered?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of talking and testing, I've found that `$s` with `setTimeout` isn't very reliable. I've set up page 7 again to demonstrate.

1. If you click the Rowaddrow button twice in rapid succession (the second time before the first `setValue` returns), the second row will not be initialized. I'll show you a workaround for this below, but you'll
2. If you lower the `setTimeout` to, say, 10 ms, and try focusing in the Expiry Date column before clicking the Rowaddrow button, you'll find it doesn't work. This means that, while the `setTimeout` of 100 ms works now, it could break in the future if the IGs internal logic changed. Unlikely but who knows.

For the moment, I would say that `$s` can only be reliably used to set a column value in an IG for the active row. When the row-add-row action adds a new record, it does make it active, but that is done asynchronously via `setTimeout`. This is because the IG is based on the flyweight pattern and there are a number of async (`setTimeout` based) heuristics that are built in to handle focus and blur events to correctly enable and disable rows and cells as needed.

I've found the following to be the most reliable solution. Unfortunately, it's more complex than what you had before - but it was the only way I could wrangle it all together. Feel free to use it or not. See page 8 for an example.

Right-click the custom **Rowaddrow** button and select **Create Dynamic Action**. Set the **Name** of the DA to **rowAddRow button clicked**. The **When** settings will automatically be configured for the click event on the button.

Select the action for the new DA. Set **Action** to **Execute JavaScript** and enter the following JavaScript in the **Code** attribute.

```
addRowClicked = true; // Global used to distinguish custom button click
this.triggeringElement.disabled = true; // Disable button to serialize access
apex.region("KITCHEN_SHARE_DTL").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("row-add-row");
```

Create a new Dynamic Action and set the **Name** to **New row initialized**. In the When section, set **Event** to **Row Initialization [Interactive Grid]**, **Section Type** to **Region**, and **Region** to **KITCHEN_SHARE_DTL**.

Under Client-Side Condition, set **Type** to **JavaScript expression** and enter the following code in **JavaScript Expression** (which ensures the DA only fires for the click of the Rowaddrow button):

```
addRowClicked === true
```

Select the action for the new DA. Set **Action** to **Set Value**, **Set Type** to **Static Assignment**, and **Value** to **2**. In Affected Elements, set **Section Type** to **Column(s)** and **Column(s)** to **INGREDIENT_ID**. This will replace the static assignment that was being done with `$s`. Ensure that **Fire on Initialization** is disabled.

Right-click the **True** branch for the DA and select **Create TRUE Action**. Set the **Action** to **Set Value**, **Set Type** to **SQL Statement**, and enter the following code in **SQL Statement**:

```
select MIN(EXPIRY_DATE) from stock
where ingredient_id = TO_NUMBER(:INGREDIENT_ID);
```

Set **Items to Submit** to **INGREDIENT_ID** and disable **Escape Special Characters**. In Affected Elements, set **Selection Type** to **Column(s)** and **Column(s)** to **EXPIRY_DATE**. Ensure that **Fire on Initialization** is disabled.

Right-click the **True** branch for the DA and select **Create TRUE Action**. Set **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code** and enter the following JavaScript in the **Code** attribute.

```
addRowClicked = false; // Unset the global
$x('ADD').disabled = false; // Enable the button
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help. Using $s() causes defined dynamic actions to fire. and that's something I'd need. BTW: John Snyders said once that they use that way in some api.

Comment: How is the When section of the DA set up?

Comment: when -> click> button> rowAddRow. Execution Scope = static. Are you asking about a specific attribute?

Comment: So, you want this to be fired once, even though you are setting the values of multiple rows, right? What is the action(s)?

Comment: No. Not at all. When adding a new row using "row-add-row" the new rows becomes the active record. Then $s() set's the column's value of that record.
Kindly, see Salim's solution below.

Comment: Let me clear something up... Are you trying to set the column value for only the new row, or all the previous rows plus the new row? One other question: do you have a DA set to respond to the change event on the column that you’re updating?

Comment: Only the new row. Yes, I have a dynamic action on the column being set and on other columns. Have you checked the sample page I've created?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request. I've updated the code in the answer and I've updated your demo app (see page 7).

Comment: This could only work if the dynamic actions do not have to do with columns of current row for example, setting the current row's values, or one has many dynamic actions on current row's columns. I'd appreciate if you could learn me the problem with my solution. What's happening with setting the first row when trying to set it's columns values?

Comment: What do you mean with respect to the DAs not working?

Comment: The DA you're using in your model is of an "Alert" type. In my case for example, the ingredient_id column has an on change PL/SQL DA which gets the minimum expiry date of the ingredient. The solution you provided will not make it fire.  Imagine I have number of other on change da's. My model will simplify the whole procedure. Not to mention that 2 lines of code are better than 3+. Besides that I am really curious why my solution is not working with the first record and works with later added records.

Comment: Regarding the DA not working, could you please show me a page where the `$s` solution is working? I've set up page 8 in your demo app as I think you're describing, but I can't get it to work. I'm happy to try and track down the difference with you.

Comment: Prior to the IG, APEX was mostly server-side processing and then a little bit of DOM scripting and Ajax on the client. The IG is a big shift in that it's based on an MVC (or MVVM) architecture. With MVC, you should work with the model, not the DOM. It's a major shift for APEX and APEX devs, so there's bound to be some pain points along the way. I'm guessing the designer of the IG APIs didn't intend for them to be used as you're using them. When we get all of this sorted out, I can check with the team to see if they think it's a bug or not.

Comment: $s() is capable of setting a column item's value of an active IG record. So, when you switch IG's Edit mode to true, you can then set any column's value of the active row. 'row-add-row' adds a row to the IG and set edit mode to true. That's why $s() works. 
According to John Snyders they use that way in some API that unfortunately, do not remember but I am sure about it because I was the one who started a thread where I get that answer. 
Kindly, see page 8 again. The only problem I have is that there is always a record that's not set.
BTW: Are you one of Apex team?

Comment: I had to update the code to use the `setTimeout` but I can verify that the Set Value DA works now. I'll feed this back to the team. I have some ideas on how this could work a little better (e.g. allowing DAs to subscribe to model changes in addition to DOM events), but they may have decided against that for some reason. I'm not on the APEX team, but I work alongside it as a Developer Advocate for APEX. Salim is on the APEX team.

Comment: I think creating, refreshing, rendering and initialization of the grid are the reason for the problem. When I ran the page in debug mode while getting the browser console open, I have seen a reference for these processes. They might be taking some time to be processed. I also think That's why if you set "add row if empty" attribute to yes, it works well Because all the previous operations take place when you first run the page. Thanks Dan for following through.

Comment: I spoke with John on the development team. I will update my answer above with some findings and options shortly.

Comment: It seems I wrote too soon. While writing up the solution I identified some new issues. Stay tuned... :)

Comment: Can not wait to hear it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const
widget = apex.region("staticRegionId").widget(),
view  = widget.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView"),
model = widget.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model,
selection = view.getSelectedRecords(),
recId = model.insertNewRecord(undefined,selection[selection.length-1]);
model.setRecordValue(recId,'DESCR','Your Description Here');
```

Notes (see also [Oracle Apex docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/model.html)):

- $s() didn't work for me, so different approach.
- model.insertNewRecord takes a record - NOT a record id - to insert the new record after (as 2nd argument). It returns the newly created record-id (temporary id).
- model.setRecordValue uses the column name, not any static-id.
- The IG must be Edit enabled, and have 'Add Row' as an Allowed Operation.